# Javascript native /regex/ have different behavior to new RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a password strength regex, apparently there is a different behavior using same regex steing, but different way to create it.

So i have one regex using slash slash closing / /
And the other one is using new RegExp(string)

```
var password ="Password123";
var regex1 = new RegExp("((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{6,})");
var regex2 = /((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{6,})/;

var result1 = regex1.test(password);
var result2 = regex2.test(password);

document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = result1;
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = result2;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hansyulian/cnxzj262/

`result1` is `true`, which is wrong, while `result2` is `false` which is correct

Anyone have idea what happened? Is this a bug?

Comment: The first one returns `true` because you told it to match a string that contains at least 1 `d` letter  with `"(?=.*\d)"`. Double escape backslashes in constructor notation to define literal backslashes.

Comment: Oh myyy!!!! Yeaa i missed this concept.... thanx man... this explain the thing